# how to add Node_modules folder into the angular project

Tags: angular, node-modules, npm-install

Node_modules folder has been deleted now I want to install it but not getting installed event I have use cache clean command, then `npm install` still node modules folder not creating below is the error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: easy-recon@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~12.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.17" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.2.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-18T07_48_59_835Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Shree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-18T07_48_59_835Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried command  like `npm install` then `npm cache clean` and again `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a dependency conflict.
You can use:

```
npm i --force
```

to install it anyways and then resolve the conflict.

Comment: or `npm i --legacy-peer-code`